# Function taking an array filled with structures, and returning a bigger array with the same structures

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct FriendInfo
    {
        string name;
        int last_day;
    };

FriendInfo GrowArray(FriendInfo friend_list,int sizing);

int main()
{
    int initial_friends;
    cout << "How many friends would you like to add--> ";
    cin >> initial_friends;
    FriendInfo friends[initial_friends];
    for (int i = 0; i < initial_friends;i++)
    {
        cout << "What is your friend's name?--> ";
        cin >> friends[i].name;
        cout << "When was the last time you talked to " << friends[i].name << " ?--> ";
        cin >> friends[i].last_day;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < initial_friends;i++)
        cout << friends[i].name << " " << friends[i].last_day << "\n";
    cout << "What would you like to do now?\n1. Add another friend?\n2. Update one of yourfriends?\n3. Sort friends by day?4. Quit.\n--> ";
    int option;
    cin >> option;
    while (option != 4)
    {
        if (option == 1)
        {
            friends = GrowArray(friends,initial_friends);
            cout << "What is your new friend's name?--> ";
            cin >> friends[initial_friends].name;
            cout << "When was the last time you talked to " << friends[initial_friends].name << " ?--> ";
            cin >> friends[initial_friends].last_day;
        }

    }
}

FriendInfo GrowArray(FriendInfo friend_list, int sizing)
{
     FriendInfo new_list[sizing + 1];
     for (int i = 0;i < sizing;i++)
     {
         new_list[i].name = friend_list[i].name;
         new_list[i].last_day = friend_list.last_day;
 }
 return new_list;
}
```

This program put structures into an array that hold a friend's name, and the last day they talked to them. One of the options later on is to add another friend. The function GrowArray takes the initial array with the friends and the days, makes another array with an extra spot and copies the original array into the new one. But when I use the function I get this error --> error: could not convert '(FriendInfo*)(& friends)' from 'FriendInfo*' to 'FriendInfo'. What's wrong?

Comment: Why on earth would you not just use `std::vector`? VLAs are not standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign `friends` like that since it's not a pointer, it's an array.
Even if you could, what you're doing isn't safe since `GrowArray` just creates a new array on the stack which will be destroyed when the function returns.

You should either use `new` and `delete` to create and destroy the arrays (you can then then pass them around as pointers), or preferably, use `std::vector` which handles all this stuff for you.

Comment: +1, and passing the vector by-reference, in case it wasn't obvious to the OP, and judging by the original posted code, it won't be. Or throw out the entire concept of the function and just use `push_back()` for what it was made for.